# Is it possible to indent the contents of an HTML textarea without displaying the indentation?

Tags: html

For example, the first line in the textarea below is not indented in the html code but the second is indented.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <body>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50">
    A line with no indentation but I would prefer if it were indented in the code
        A line that displays with unwanted indentation
        </textarea>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Anything you enter between the `<textarea>` and `</textarea>` tags will be displayed verbatim (= as is) in the textbox. This includes line feeds and blanks.

Answer (score 2):

A `textarea` element has the CSS property `white-space` set to `pre` by default. This preserves whitespaces in the element, rather than the default of ignoring them. The value `pre-line` does what you want: it preserves linebreaks, but not other whitespace. You can read about [other options at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
      <textarea rows="8" cols="50" style="white-space: pre-line">
A line with no indentation but I would prefer if it were indented in the code
    A line that displays with unwanted indentation

          As a potentially unwanted side effect, 
          white-space     in-line    is ignored as well.
    </textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

Run this snippet and you'll see that 'A line...' will wrap to a new line (because there is a linebreak) but it will not be indented.

Answer (score 0):

As cars10m mentioned, textarea displays whatever you type in it 'as-is'. However, you can use JavaScript in order to fix the content on page load and on input.

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sample").val($(".sample").val().replace(/\s\s+/g, ' '));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" class="sample">
A line with no indentation but I would prefer if it were indented in the code
    A line that displays with unwanted indentation
</textarea>
```